# Making banner up and down scale

Tags: html, css

I have problem making my banners up and down my webpage scale to always fit the user's screen so I don't have horizontal scroll bars which is bad experience on mobile phones as desktops as well. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">      
      <style type="text/css">
      body {
              background-image: url("TBG_02.jpg");
              background-color: #cccccc;
              background-size: cover;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
           }
        #top,#bottom{width:100%;}
        #top,#bottom{height:155px;}
        #top{position: fixed;left:0;top:0;}
        #bottom{position: fixed;right:0;bottom:0;}
        .topp{background-image: url("BG_02.png");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;}
        .bottomm{background-image:url("BG_03.png");background-repeat: no-repeat;position:fixed;background-size: cover;}
      </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="top" class="topp">
</div>
<div id="bottom" class="bottomm">
</div>   
</body>
```

And this is how the problem looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjWsP.jpg

You may notice the bad gray/white space in the photo as well. To note: I will add some images as buttons above the banners. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is basically sound in using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

to ensure that the browser resizes the image to cover the whole of the `<body>`.

What you are missing though, is that the height of the body *does not* cover the whole height of the viewport.

To fix this, you can add:

```
body {min-height: 100vh;}
```

**ie.** *the height of the body must never be less than 100% the height of the viewport (or 100 **viewport-height** units).*

**Working Example:**

```css
body, .top, .bottom {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}

body {
min-height: 100vh;
background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/414171/pexels-photo-414171.jpeg');
}
         
.top, .bottom{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.top{
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.bottom{
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Well from snippet it is working as i want but .. In my project , The background image is maximized *as it is bigger than my current screen* and those banners disappeared :(

Comment: Try declaring: `body {min-height: 100vh; max-height: 100vh;}`

Comment: Along with this, the `overflow: auto` to esnure that the page is scrollable when it has more content.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Rounin was cool but it made some troubles; the only thing it missed is that there is no image to put in the divs so they can appear on the banners, then I had to set their width and height and playing with them a bit until it fixed :D

```
<body>
  <div class="top">
    <img src="BG_02.png" class="top"/>
  </div<
</body>
```